# Difference between this two programs

Tags: java, compiler-construction

Assume the 2 following programs :

```
public class Main {

    private static boolean test= false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(test)
            method1();
    }

    private static void method1() {
        //Some stuff
        method2();
    }

    private static void method2() {
        //Some stuff
    }

}
```

---

```
   public class Main {

        private final static boolean test= false;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            if(test)
                method1();
        }

        private static void method1() {
            //Some stuff
            method2();
        }

        private static void method2() {
            //Some stuff
        }

    }
```

---

For the second one, I would say that the compiler won't generate `bytecode` for `method1()` and `method2()` since `test` is `final` and set to `false`.

Would it generate `bytecode` for the first case ? And if yes, why ?

**EDIT :**

Compiler output for the first :

```
public class Main extends java.lang.Object{
static{};
Code :
0: iconst_0
1: putstatic #10; //Field test:Z
4: return

public Main();
Code :
0: aload_0
1: invokespecial #15; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":<>V
4: return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
Code :
0: getstatic #10; //Field test:Z
3: ifeq 9
6: invokestatic #21; //Method method1:()V
9: return
```

Compiler output for the second:

```
public class Main extends java.lang.Object{
public Main();
Code :
0: aload_0
1: invokespecial #12; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":<>V
4: return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
Code :
0: return
```

Comment: What did you try before asking?

Comment: The only difference I see is that the test variable is final in the second.  Maybe my eyes missed some other differences.

Comment: @CodeChimp - In theory, `static final` variables may be treated the same as C macro "switches" and turn on or off code, to the point of it not even being generated (though they won't turn off syntax checking).  I've never really dug into this, though -- it's kinda half-arsed IMO.

Comment: What Jon said -- try it, use `javap` to print the bytecodes, and see how the two versions differ.

Comment: (My guess is that the methods will still be generated, just the call will be omitted.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I saw that the compiler did'nt generate `bytecode`  for the second case and did for the first one, but I can't figure out why

Comment: @CodeChimp I'm talking about this difference

Comment: You obviously haven't listed all of the bytecode disassemblies.  I'm curious as to whether the (not) called methods went away.

Comment: Makes sense, since the code optimizer could make the assumption to not include the method since it know its false and will never change.

Comment: @HotLicks Sorry (this is an old thread), but I listed the bytecode of the second snippet (javap -c Main.class) and this is the output.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: it will generate byte code for both methods in both examples, of course. If you quickly compile both classes and decompile the classes afterwards, you'll see that everything is existing.

However, if you use an obfuscator this might be different.

Cheers!